# Passing checkbox values of a form as JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, checkbox

Html code :

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" id="addpersons" style="padding:20px;">
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend class="scheduler-border">Information</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="fname" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="lname" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="professionalservices">Do you offer any of the services?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="width:70%; margin-left:34%;">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="professionalservices-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="professionalservices" id="professionalservices-0" value="1">
        BI  services
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="professionalservices-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="professionalservices" id="professionalservices-1" value="2">
      Resell vendor's  services
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="professionalservices-2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="professionalservices" id="professionalservices-2" value="3">
      Consulting Services
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="professionalservices-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="professionalservices" id="professionalservices-3" value="4">
      Other  servies
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="professionalservices-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="professionalservices" id="professionalservices-4" value="5">
      No  services
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
         <a href="javascript:addperson();" class="btn btn-success">Apply Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Json Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

   function addperson(){

        alert("hello");
        var persons = JSON.stringify({
        "firstName": $('#fname').val(), 
        "lastName":$('#lname').val(),
        "Services":$('#services').val()


       });

    alert("test values are"+persons);
    console.log(persons);

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: 'application/json',
           url: baseurl+"addperson/add",
           data: persons,
           dataType:"text",
           success:successmethod,
           error: function(data,status) {
            alert("Error  "+status);
           }
          });

   }
   function successmethod(data){
    alert("sucessfully stored values");
   }
   </script>
```

In the above  code am able to take the values of each textbox but when it comes to checkbox,i want to retrive multiple checkbox values inside json and want to pass it to Ajax.Can anyone tell me how can i take the multiple checkbox values in to Json??Any Help would be Appreciated..

Comment: please dont downvote the question unnecessarily everything is fine in the question that has been asked and getting answers from people..then why the hell is the question downvoted..

Comment: Yes it's getting answers, did you find yourself saying *"it is not working"* and the answerers replying *"i tried and it was giving a json string.say me the format which you need"* ? that means the question is incomplete, they're just assuming what is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this to get checked values:

```
$( "#services:checked" ).map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get()
```

In your case this will be something like this:

```
    var persons = JSON.stringify({
    "firstName": $('#fname').val(), 
    "lastName":$('#lname').val(),
    "Services": $( "#services:checked" ).map(function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get()
   });
```

Comment: by this am getting the checkbox values but it is saving only one value instead of multiple values in database..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take the whole form with jQuery [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/):

```
data: $('form#addpersons').serializeArray();
```

Will get what you want and greatly shorten your code.

Its Javascript code by the way not JSON code. ;)

Try:

```
function addperson(){

        var persons =  $('form#addpersons').serializeArray();
        console.log(persons);

       });
```

Comment: i tried the above method but its not working...

Comment: jQuery is the way to go, simple short and let the framework to serialise the form.

Answer (score 0):

Mark it as answer if it helps you.
change your function addperson()

```
function addperson(){
    var objJson={};
    objJson["firstName"]=$('#fname').val();
    objJson["lastName"]=$('#lname').val();
    objJson["Services"]={};
    $.each( $('input[type=checkbox]'), function(i, left) {
        objJson["Services"][$(this).parent().text().trim()]=$(this).prop("checked");
    });
    var persons = JSON.stringify(objJson);
    alert("test values are"+persons);
    console.log(persons);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       url: baseurl+"addperson/add",
       data: persons,
       dataType:"text",
       success:successmethod,
       error: function(data,status) {
        alert("Error  "+status);
       }
     });
```

}

Comment: this is not working at all..

Comment: i tried and it was giving a json string.say me the format which you need